# DDP (Drawloop) Compile - what does it do?

Tags: community

[image: what does Compile do -when is it useful?]

Wondering what the compile button does and when is it useful. My main problem is that I've updated a document and successfully use the associated DDP with the new version but the end user doesn't get the updated doc.

Answer (score 2):

"Compile" is a process Drawloop does whenever a document or a DDP record is updated. You can also hit it from the DDP. "Compile" allows us to optimize the processing on subsequent requests to the same DDP.  On this issue I would recommend you reach out to our support team.  The user should see the updated document in either case.  We will help you find out where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

when `compile` button is clicked it redirects to loop website with your

- Salesforce current session id as `$API.Session_id`
- Partner API URL as `$API.Partner_Server_URL_300`
- DDP id as `$API.loop__ddp__c.id`)

As query parameters to `https://apps.drawloop.com/sflogin.aspx?sessionid={!API.Session_ID}&location={!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_300}&next=/ddps/42/7?ddpId={!Loop__DDP__c.Id}` on DDP on which you have triggered that compile button & it verifies the all related records that have defined in `relationships`,`Insert-Updates` and used the field tagger as `Merge field` name that are using on `Delivery Document` which generates the document, the format of document your have defined(doc/pdf/excel).

I hope you get idea what compile button does. Let me know in case of any further information.

Comment: Thanks very much The Ajay Gupta! Thorough and complete answer.

Comment: Please upvote!! if you like the answer :)

Comment: I did upvote but I'm a newbie so need a better reputation :(

Comment: asking another root question now so my reputation is bound to improve.